# Сколько звездочек позволяет ставить компилятор Си?

Tags: указатели, c, компилятор

int *a итд ) Задротский вопросик, разминаем мозги.

Answer (score 2):

Для компилятора что `int *a`, что `int *********a` это просто указатель.

Это вопрос в том как сделан парсер. Думаю много. Напишите скрипт генерирующий сишный код и 
компилирующий его дабы проверить.

**UPD0**: Неважно сколько звёздочек, указатель и в африке указатель. [Здесь](https://gist.github.com/964474) подтверждение этому.

Comment: "Для компилятора что int *a, что int *********a это просто указатель"
нет, не так. Для компилятора это переменные разных типов. Следовательно, в зависимости от реализации мы или можем написать int *a = *********a напрямую или не можем и придется использовать явное приведение или cast.

Comment: "Напишите скрипт генерирующий сишный код и компилирующий его дабы проверить."
Интересней написать скрипт, который генерирует код int *a; int **a; int ***a; int ****a; и т.д. При этом, учитывая, что компиляторы оптимизирующие было б неплохо погонять это как тест в разных режимах. С шаблонами, например, у компиляторов крышу бывает сносит на ура. Так и тут могут быть проблемы. Но не для тривиальных вариантов по крайней мере.

Comment: "Неважно сколько звёздочек, указатель и в африке указатель"
согласен. Разница только во время компиляции на уровне анализа кода.

Comment: **разминаем мозги** - ну тогда ответ известен: ***; *****; КС; КВВК. Других комбинаций не знаю.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Куда интереснее не просто количество звездочек, а получение при этом нормального поведения. А тут разыменование указателя на функцию не сравнится ни с чем :)

```
int dbl(int x)
{
    return x*2;
}

int (*f)(int) = dbl;

int main()
{
    cout << (**************f)(5) << " ";
}
```

Visual C++ 2015 справился с 1516 звездочками, на 1517-й выдал - "слишком сложная программа"...

Comment: gcc/clang спокойно скопмилировали 2000 звездочек.